# Strange Castle AddFacility runtime error

Tags: nhibernate, castle-windsor, castle, castle-autotx

I'am new to Castle and Castle.Windsor, so this is maybe a noob question.

I created an empty console .NET 4.0 application and added next packages through NuGet:

1. Castle Windsor factory support facility 3.0 beta 1 (3.0.2001)
2. Castle Windsor 3.0 beta 1 (3.0.2001)
3. Castle Core 3.0 beta 1 (3.0.2001)
4. Castle NHibernate facility (0.5.1.4000)
5. Fluent NHibernate (1.3.0.717)
6. NHibernate (3.2.0.4000)
7. Iesi Collections (3.2.0.4000)

and wrote next code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

        container.AddFacility<AutoTxFacility>();
        //container.AddFacility<NHibernateFacility>();
    }
```

But I got an error:

> GenericArguments[0], 'TService', on 'Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.RegistrationGroup`1[S]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'S'.

If rewrite code and uncomment second AddFacility line:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

        //container.AddFacility<AutoTxFacility>();
        container.AddFacility<NHibernateFacility>();
    }
```

I got next error:

> Could not load type 'Castle.Facilities.FactorySupport.FactorySupportFacility' from assembly 'Castle.Windsor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc'.

I tried add `container.AddFacility<Castle.Facilities.FactorySupport.FactorySupportFacility>();` line before first AddFacility but it not solve a problem.

In real application I got another error for same try and same libraries:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Castle.Windsor, Version=2.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

with next FusionLog:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Castle.Windsor, Version=2.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc
(Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///xxx.Test/bin/Debug
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : Castle.Facilities.AutoTx, Version=3.0.202.2202, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc.
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: xxx.Test\bin\Debug\xxx.Test.dll.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Castle.Windsor, Version=2.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///xxx.Test/bin/Debug/Castle.Windsor.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

I don't understand what I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the version of AutoTx facility you're using was compiled against older version of Windsor.

I'm not sure if the facility supports Windsor 3 yet, probably the best course of action is to ask at [castle user googole group](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users)